# Did paypal recently change its validation rules?

Tags: paypal

Wake up this morning to the following error from paypal:

```
{u'message': u'Invalid request - see details', u'debug_id': u'e2cbb28b0ff6f', 
 u'information_link': u'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR',
 u'name': u'VALIDATION_ERROR', 
 u'details': [{u'field': u'payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.last_name', 
               u'issue': u'Required field missing'}, 
              {u'field': u'payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.first_name', 
              u'issue': u'Required field missing'}]}
```

does anyone know if paypal changed it's policy about first_name and last_name or they've just made a buggy release?

we were able to process thousands of paypal payments without a first name and last name until this morning.

Comment: Just checked it. All my IPN's work fine without it. Strange.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert did you find any problems?

Comment: @grimv01k interestingly, ours doesn't and it was working without any problems until 2 am this morning.